# How is this tool called for sorting out wires on newly installed patch panels?

Tags: network

I've lost my tool I use frequently. Since I don't know the name for the tool I am having a hard time to find a replacement.

[image: Text]

How is above tool called? It is meant for patch panels to correct faulty wires and such.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've normally heard them referred to as a "wire pick". Here's an example image I found:

[image]

That image came from [Lewis Contractor Sales](https://www.lewiscontractorsales.com/klein-tool-wire-pick.html) that I've never dealt with but they sell them as a single part. More commonly I've seen them either as an integral component of a punch-down tool or included as part of a punch-down kit.

Answer (score 0):

is it this? your drawing looks like a punch down tool. [image]

Comment: I understand your reply and I have that tool already. It is the other side of the tool I use most. Just a thin steel thing that can take quite some force in regard to it's thickness.